# can't call .bat file from within another - "not recognized as an internal or external command" error

Tags: windows, batch-file

i tried looking at the other questions regarding this, but no go. i've tried a straight call to the other bat file ("otherBat.bat," for instance), a "call" command, and even a "start" command. all of these are failing though, and i'm at a loss as to why. both .bat files are within the same folder, and i'm not changing directories, so i don't know what the problem is...

any help on this would be much appreciated ^_^

edit: sorry, here's the code :)

primary.bat:

```
echo Test run...enter variable1
set /p var1=:


echo Test run...enter variable2
set /p var2=:


call other.bat %var1% %var2%

pause
```

other.bat:

```
echo Working!
pause
```

Comment: can you paste the batch code please

Comment: Are you sure it is the second batch file that is 'not recognized...' and not a command in that second batch file?

Comment: Make sure you are in "echo on" state, so you could be sure what's going on

Comment: yeah, the second batch's commands are good

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You should either cd to the current directory in your first batch file or call the second batch file by full path.

Comment: WOW, you're right, i was in the wrong directory. facepalm. -_-

Answer (score 1):

Is the second .bat file in your path? What happens if you change your first .bat file to call it using an absolute path?

Answer (score 1):

use the absolute path :

```
::prototype 
CALL [drive:][path]filename [parameters]

::example
call C:\Users\theUserName\path-to-your-file\the-file-name.bat %your-variables-to-pass%
```

cf [the **call documentation** from ss64.com](https://ss64.com/nt/call.html)

Answer (score 0):

Absolute path may be replaced with `%~dp0\`, which means use current script's path instead of runtime context; in your case `call %~dp0\other.bat %var1% %var2%`.

Had same issue when running as administrator from context menu – `call` tried to execute batch file in *System32* instead of parent BAT folder.